# Como aumentar o limite de conexões do MongoDB?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mongodb

Bom dia. Tenho um server Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, hospedado no Linode. Ontem passei a noite inteira lendo artigos e testando configurações para aumentar a capacidade de conexões do MongoDB, mas nada funcionou. No momento o mongo está com 819 disponíveis, que seria 80% de 1024.

Tentei aumentar o limite de file descriptors com o comando `ulimit -n 64000` porém o mesmo só afeta meu usuário, e após relogar volta para 1024.

Alterei o arquivo `/etc/sysctl.conf` e adicionei a linha `fs.file-max = 64000`, mas não funcionou.

Alterei o arquivo `/etc/security/limits.conf` e adicionei as seguintes linhas, uma a uma para testar (sempre reiniciando o server entre cada alteração):

`* - nofile 64000
root - nofile 64000
mongodb - nofile 64000
mongodb - nproc 64000`

Após essa configuração o `ulimit -a` retorna:

`core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 48041
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 64000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 48041
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited`

Criei o arquivo `/etc/security/limits.d/99-mongodb-nproc.conf` com a configuração `* - nofile 64000` e também não funcionou.

Também coloquei a linha `session required pam_limits.so` nos arquivos `/etc/pam.d/common-session` e `/etc/pam.d/common-session-noninteractive` e nada.

Meu `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service` está executando o mongod com o argumento `--maxConns 51200` e o `mongo.conf` está com `maxIncomingConnections: 51200`

Quando executo o comando `db.serverStatus().connections` no shell do mongo, ele me retorna `{ "current" : 9, "available" : 810, "totalCreated" : NumberLong(68349) }`.

Já não sei mais o que tentar. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Bom dia @ataquino, você chegou a reiniciar o servidor? estas alterações envolvem modificação dos parâmetros do kernel e talvez necessitem de um reboot da máquina.

Comment: Esqueci de informar que a cada alteração eu reiniciava o serviço e se não funcionasse reiniciava o servidor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consegui ajuda por fora do stackoverflow e aparentemente é um bug da versão 3.2.8: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-25080.

Em outro servidor eu possuo a versão 3.2.11 instalada, mas mesmo repetindo todos os passos acima não funcionou. Acabei aplicando o workaround contido nesse link e funcionou:

> For my system I made a quick fix by creating file named /etc/systemd/system/mongod.service.d/ulimit.conf (you should create mongod.service.d directory, file name itself is arbitrary) with following contents:
>
> [Service]
> LimitFSIZE=infinity
> LimitCPU=infinity
> LimitAS=infinity
> LimitNOFILE=64000
> LimitNPROC=64000